Failed to import transformers.integrations.peft

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import transformers.integrations.peft because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flash_attn_2_cuda.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at4_ops5zeros4callEN3c108ArrayRefINS2_6SymIntEEENS2_8optionalINS2_10ScalarTypeEEENS6_INS2_6LayoutEEENS6_INS2_6DeviceEEENS6_IbEE

This is the Error , i am using jupyter notebook on portrainer.
Any Help would be appreciated. I am completely newbie working in field of LLM and RAG

This seems to relate to problems with the compatibility of installed versions. Similar issues are reported here and here. You could try reinstalling torch or switching to a more current version of it.
